# Problemas con el UTF-8

Tags: html, utf-8

Buen dia mi gente, por que en mi localhost la pag me sale con simbolos raros las letras acentuadas pero ya subida en el host me sale bien.

Si tengo las etiquetas `<meta charset="utf-8">` y `<html lang="es">`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esta pregunta en cierto momento ya se hizo y respondió aquí en la comunidad, trata de seguirla mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%C3%A1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base/59510#59510

Comment: Gracias, paso a revisar el tema

Comment: Se escribe esp y no es intenta con ese cambio y me avisas además debes de checar qué tengas el Doctype HTML al inicio indicando que es un archivo html5

Comment: de hecho escribir `es` es perfectamente válido y si notas además ya esta usando la etiqueta `meta` para indicar el `charset` necesario